# System.Collections.Generic.Find() vs Linq.First()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can anyone tell me when to use Find() and When to use First() ? Is one better than the other if you just want a simple query to find a specific item in the list?

Comment: Do you mean `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Find()` ?

Answer (score 10):

If it's possible for the default value of the type of your list (that is, null for reference types, zero for numeric types, and the result of calling the default constructor for other value types) to be a correct "found it" result, and if it's important that you distinguish this from it not being found, then you need to use `First()` as it will throw an exception on not finding anything, while `Find()` will return the default value.

So. Do you want an exception in this case or no?

That distinction aside, `Find()` is pretty much the same as `FirstOrDefault()`, which also returns the default when it finds nothing.

Use `Find()` in .NET2.0, since you don't have `FirstOrDefault()`.

Use `Find()` if it's about the only thing you'd be adding a reference to `System.Core` for, though this is hardly a big issue (it's not like `System.Core` isn't commonly used and available with all the framework versions).

Use `FirstOrDefault()` if you want to call it on something other than a `List<T>`.
Use `FirstOrDefault()` if you *might* want to call it on something other than a `L
ist<T>` in the future.

Use `Find()` if you really care about the trivial performance difference, but if you do you'd be better writing your own method that spun through the list and didn't use a delegate anyway.

Use `FirstOrDefault()` if your predicate is `item => true`, because you can call the form that takes no predicate. That said, you could use `list[0]` anyway.

Use `FirstOrDefault()` if you're mixing it in with other Linq, as it'll read more consistent that way.

None of the above are exactly earth-shattering differences though. Really, the difference between the two is pretty minor, and I doubt `Find()` would have been written had `FirstOrDefault()` been added in the same framework version.

Answer (score 3):

`First()` returns first element from the sequence or first from a sequence that satisfy the condition. The method `First()` throws an exception when sequence is *empty*.  The `Find()` method searches an element that matches the condition. If search element is not found then it returns *default* value for type `T`.

Some cool SO threads:

1. [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)
2. [Regarding FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651087/regarding-firstordefault-or-singleordefault)

Comment: So the question should be `Find` vs. `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Modified answer to include a note about Find vs FirstOrDefault

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Do you want to update your post or mine. Budy, you've update my post.

Comment: @AVD Apologies it was me who updated your post, not Daniel. Did it by accident, as you suggest I was intending to update my post.

Answer (score 0):

`First()` returns the first element from the sequence, throwing an exception if the source sequence is empty or no match is found. `Find()` method searches for an element that matches the condition returning the default value for the type if no match is found.

Comment: So the question should be `Find` vs. `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

They basically do the same thing, with the exception of First() throwing an exception if the  match does not exist. FirstOrDefault is pretty much the match for Find().

For anyone interested, First() and Find() work in a slightly different manner though.

This is the (approximate) find loop in Find() extracted from List<T>. It uses array indexing.

```
    int num = 0;
    num++;
    while (num < this._size)
        if (match(this._items[num]))
            return this._items[num];
    T t = default(T);

    return t;
```

First() uses enumeration and thus  works on any enumerable collection

```
    foreach (TSource tSource in source)
        if (predicate(tSource))
            return tSource;

    throw Error.NoMatch();
```

This *should* allow for Find() to have a slight speed advantage due to no Enumerator overhead.

Comment: Surely you mean "this should allow `Find()` to have a slight speed advantage"?

Comment: I do it all the time. Or I either add or omit a "not" and end up saying the opposite to what I mean :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson nice catch! I ran a few tests and the Find is really faster and it's not somewhat slight, there's a solid difference. Find runs almost as twice as faster. Pls see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault)