# c# lambda take FirstOrDefault property if it is not null

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to check if FirstOrDefault() is not null, and if not, take some property. My best bet is:

```
var results = Database.Set<Pizzas>().Select(x => new PizzaViewModel
{
    Base = Database.Set<Bases>().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.Base.Id) != null ? Database.Set<Bases>().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.Base.Id).Name : null
}).ToList();
```

Is there better way to do this?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu Again, that is not a duplicate. Don't throw duplicates that are not an answer to the question.

Comment: This looks like a custom implemented outer join. You might consider read into [outer joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq).

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu dublicate you provided doesn't answer my question, since all answers provide similar queries to mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use null propagation operator on `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
Base = Database.Set<Bases>().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.Base.Id)?.Name
```

Comment: Its fine to get one property, how to achieve `take some properties`/? let it be some `name` and `age`

Comment: "some property" is singular, right? @un-lucky "properties" is plural.

Comment: Its probably worth mentioning the c# version requirement - some people are for various reasons stuck using older versions that don't support this. :(

Comment: Try to use `Find(...)` instead of `FirstOrDefault(...)` if possible.

Comment: Why? There is nothing to `Find`... This code does what it should.

Comment: Hava a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yep, Then how can I use this code to retrieve `.Name` and `.Age` properties?

Comment: That is not the question. The questions is "property". @un-lucky

Answer (score 3):

Since someone mentioned multiple properties I'll add this in, the let allows us to keep the base so that we can query it for multiple things, and the null propagation operator allows us to make sure we're not breaking if there was no base found.

```
var bases = Database.Set<Bases>();
var results =
    (from pizza in Database.Set<Pizzas>()
    let pizzaBase = bases.FirstOrDefault(pizzaBase => pizzaBase.Id == pizza.Base.Id)
    select new PizzaViewModel {
        Base = pizzaBase?.Name,
        BaseIngredients = pizzaBase?.Ingredients
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way for C# < 6.0:

```
Base = Database.Set<Bases>().Where(y => y.Id == x.Base.Id)
                            .Select(y=> y.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Otherwise, you can use the Null-Conditional Operator (`?`) operator before `.Name`